# How to pre populate a forms fields from a database using a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, database, forms

Ok so I have an html form.  This form is used to collect user/members information.  It uses a database with several columns 2 of importance "user_email" & "invoice_id".  In my form the "user_email" input is hidden and upon page load is equal to the the value of a logged in users provided email address on file.  When a user submits multiple form submissions, multiple records with the same user_email are created in my database.  So say for instance if user1 submitted 3 forms there would be 3 records in my database all with their "user_email" column value equal to that of logged in user1's email.  Trying to figure out a way to display a list of links that when clicked on will pre populate the form with with info from each record available in the database.  So if user1 is logged in and has 3 records, 3 links would be generated/displayed and each link when clicked on would pre populate the form with record data from the database.  And this is where the "invoice_id" input comes in...the links generated need to be labeled or titled with the value/text of whatever the users "invoice_id" value is for each particular record.  Note that the "user_id" input value is already auto generated and pre filled with a unique serial number ALSO upon page load...

Any help or point in the right direction to achieving this would be great.  Thanks.

```
<form action="xxx.php" class="well" id="xxx" name"xxx" method="post">


<input type="hidden" id="user_email" name="user_email" value="xxx@email.com">
<input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice_id">
<input type="text" id="other1" name="other1">
<input type="text" id="other2" name="other2">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some Ajax code using JQuery to send a query to your server side (PHP?) which in turn returns the results of a database query based on the email address. The results can be loaded into a div as HTML so the server side does all the formatting etc.

```
  function Lookup() {
    var Options = {
    };
      Options.email= ... email address from form
      $.ajax({
          url: 'Lookup.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: Options
       }).done(function(data){
                      $("#ResultDiv").html(data);
        });
    }
```

This javascript function needs to be called once the page has loaded:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   Lookup();
    }
```

PHP code would look something like this:

```
... database connect stuff
 $sSQL     = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE user_email = '".$_POST['email']."';";

  $result = RunQuery($sSQL);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

  $iLoop    = 0;
  //output results from database
  echo 'OK<table><tr>';

  while (($iLoop <= 30) && ($aRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))) {
    extract($aRow);

   echo "<tr><td><a href='".$invoice_id.".html'>".$invoice_id."</a></td><td>"
  ... other info as   required ...."</td></tr>";

    $iLoop++;

  }
  echo '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 // Get user from server
            $.post("GetUserData", data, function (result, status) {
                // Loop through each field in the returned object
                $.each(result, function (key, element) {
                    // Append the field value to the 
                    // correct field inside the form
                    $("#user_form :input[name = '" + key + "']").val(element);
                });
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                // Retrieve the error response from the title
                retrieveErrorTitle(error);
            });
```